# MySQL comparing too variables where start is different

Tags: mysql, variables, where-clause

So I want to compare this variable `colA` (for sake of simplicity lets say its value is `STEAM_1:0:90283883`).

Now I want compare `colA` with `colB` (which value is `0:90283883`).

Now this is going to be in a `where` clause, so I want it to be like this (With the variables filled in instead of actual letters)

```
WHERE 'STEAM_1:0:90283883' = '%0:90283883'
```

How would I go about this using variables? I basically want this to happen:

```
WHERE colA = ('%'colB)
```

Hope you get it, now obviously that wouldn't work, so how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use the % wildcard you need to change = to LIKE

```
WHERE 'STEAM_1:0:90283883' LIKE '%0:90283883'


WHERE colA LIKE CONCAT('%',colB)
```

Comment: Also use proper string concatenation with colB.

Comment: added that to my answer